# C++: passing structs vs providing assessor functions

Tags: c++, user-interface, frontend, backend

I have the following (POD) struct to represent the data that is needed by the frontend.

```
struct data {
    std::string foo;
    std::string bar;
    int baz;
};
```

**I have two options:**

```
class backend_option_one {
    //...
public:
    std::list<data> get_data() const;
    void set_data(std::list<data> data_list);
    void update_frontend() // asynchronous changes from the backend
};
```

**v.s.**

```
class backend_option_two {
    //...
public:
    std::string get_foo() const;
    std::string get_bar() const;
    int get_baz() const;
    void set_foo(std::string& old_foo, std::string& new);
    void set_bar(std::string& old_foo, std::string& value);
    void set_baz(std::string& old_foo, int& value);
    void add(std::string& new_foo);
    void update_frontend(); // asynchronous changes from the backend
};
```

In terms of: **re-usability**, **future-proofing**, and **good coding practice** which is the more desirable options and are there any condition where one approach is better than the other?

Comment: What are you communicating with?

Comment: The two options don't seem to be equivalent, the first returns a list of `data` while the second one seems only to be able to handle one `data` record. Is the second option missing some selector?

Comment: What kind of concurrency do you have to deal with? Are you expecting some other view to change the data while you work with it? Do you see the need to lock data elements?

Comment: @Fozi Yes they are missing. In this case foo is the unique value and used to identify a record. I'll add that in.

Comment: @Fozi yes, there are concurrent events that can change the view. I already follow a MVC so that's not the issue here.

Comment: If `foo` is the key then I suggest you make it read-only or come up with a method of renaming (in terms of my answer the change notification will have to have the old and new data) or you will run into duplication problems where one view updates foo and while another one updates something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68675/discussion-between-andre-and-fozi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution is the [Model View Controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) where your backend is the model and your GUI is the view and the controller.

The backend usually provides methods to get and set the data (all or parts of it) and implement a [subscription pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) where the views subscribe for data change notifications. This data change notification usually includes hints on what changed (indexes) or even all the changed data.

The display part of your GUI is the view, it subscribes to the model for the change notification and requests and displays the data that needs displaying.

The controller part of the pattern is done by the buttons or menus or whatnot the user is able to use to work on the data in a view. When the user changes the data you change the data on the model and all views will be notified and updated.

There is a common shortcut where the current view is already showing the changed data and does not need updating: for that case usually the update notification contains a pointer (or some other ID) of the object that did the change so that the view's update handler can ignore the change if it did it itself. This also requires that your setters on the model have an (optional) parameter that identifies the object that makes the change.

**As for how much data the model should provide (based on feedback from the chat):**

It makes sense for the model to provide getters for all the data for the initial read and also single data elements on demand. The change notification in this case could provide the changed element which is the more efficient and scalable solution.

If the whole list can change then you could also provide a setter to the model that accepts the whole list as replacement. The model could then either send multiple single element change notifications to the views or the views could have a second change handler that handles the "whole list has changed" case by a complete re-initialization.